# Lauch a web application stored in a Docker volume

Tags: docker, web-applications, volume

I fail to start my web application by typing: `localhost:8080/opt/tomcat/webapps`

Instead of the web application I get a blank page.

I typed the following command to create a container with attached volume to store my webapp:

`sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 8009:8009 -v /opt/tomcat/webapps:/opt/tomcat/webapps dordoka/tomcat`

Comment: Please show the content of `/opt/tomcat/webapps`. Do you have a .war-file in there? And what is the root context of your web application? In general what follows after `localhost:8080`is the root context your app is configured with. You cant simply put the location of your web application behind `localhost:8080` Also: Are you sure you need a volume for your task? Think about copying you web application into /opt/tomcat/webapps inside the container (`COPY /opt/tomcat/webapps /opt/tomcat/webapps` in Dockerfile) instead of doing that by using a volume.

Comment: I need a volume because the content of my webapp will be used by several containers. I don't have any war file, I just create a volume and put the content of my webapp in it